# find bip32 seed from transaction

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, seed

Based on my bip32 word list, I have a list of about 100k seed phrases that pass checksum and am trying to figure out my actual seed.
Earlier, I was derivign the xpub key and searching the blockchain for the final balance, but now, i have a transaction address.  I was wondering if there's an easier way for me to determine my actual seed using this new information.

Comment: What exactly do you have and where did you get it? Are you missing one or two words from a wallet seed? Or you forgot what order they go in? The question is a little ambiguous. Typically there is no way "find a seed". It is generated once and must be kept safe.

Comment: @pinhead Essentially, I have the 24 word list but about 6 words are written really sloppily and it's hard to decipher.  So I have a program which tests out combinations for each missing word, so in total there are approx ~100k seeds and then ~9k that pass checksum.  I need to know how do you check the balance of a seed if you have a wallet address from a previous transaction

Comment: Yikes. Well brute force may be your only hope. Derive addresses from each possible seed and check the Blockchain. We wouldn't want it to work any other way, that'd be a security failure.

Comment: @pinhead yes, but like I'm not exactly sure if the address that I derive wil lbe the same as the transaction I have a log of?  I guess I'm not sure if the python packages I'm using will guarantee that I find it, provided the correct seed is amongst my list

Comment: yeah this is an issue with bip39 in general. You *also* need to know which wallet generated the seed and which bip32 path was used to generate the addresses you received bitcoins at.

Comment: You first need to think back and try to remember what wallet you used to generate this seed phrase with. It may not even be a BIP39 mnemonic even though it uses the same wordlist.

Comment: it's on a nano ledger s

Comment: is there no way to derive the xpub key from the seed and search the blockchain using that??